# Can you say "I traveled <country>"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I'm not sure whether you can say, although I have some confidence in my English skills:

> I traveled the whole of Germany. (or just:) I traveled Germany.

It sounds vaguely wrong to me. I guess the better way would be to say:

> I traveled all over Germany.

But I don't think you can say:

> I traveled over Germany.

Right?

Comment: The phrasing I would expect to encounter would be "I traveled throughout [area]." or "I traveled all over [area].". I don't believe you can phrase the concept to avoid the preposition. Your last example, "I traveled over Germany." is grammatical, but doesn't mean what you appear to want it to mean; it implies that your plane was routed via German airspace, but both ends of the trip were in countries other than Germany. Normally, the verb in that case would be 'flew' - "I flew over Germany.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say all of those phrases in different contexts bar one. If you went on a road trip and traveled to lots of places all across Germany then you could say:

> I traveled the whole of Germany.

or

> I traveled all over Germany.

By saying

> I traveled over Germany.

you are implying that you have flown over Germany in an airplane, not that you have visited parts of Germany.

---

> I traveled Germany.

is never short for

> I traveled the whole of Germany.

and it is very unlikely that you would hear someone say it on its own.

You are more likely to hear it as part of a sentence such as:

> I traveled Germany in search of the perfect craft beer.

Comment: I think your last example should be *I **toured** Germany ...*

Comment: There's also "**travel across**"

Answer (score 2):

Only the second one—"I traveled all over Germany"—is acceptable. The other two would sound very awkward to native speakers.

The verb "travel" can take an object, but it's usually in sentences like "he traveled long distances" or "she traveled the world." It's almost never used with the name of a country.

For that, you would usually use a different verb, like "go to" or "vacation in."